# When to disregard AIC as a criterion in model selection

Tags: regression, model-selection, aic

I have the following problem: I'm working on a dataset and it looks completely quadratic. A quadratic regression fits the data really good. However, when using piecewise linear functions I get a lower AIC. For me it would not make sense to use the piecewise linear approximation as the quadratic one seems to work as well. However, is there a systematic way to argue for the quadratic model?

Comment: Either your perception of which fit is better or the implementation (how AIC is calculated) might be at fault. Have you considered both carefully?

Comment: I think an obvious point is how parsimonious the model is. I guess any function can we well approximated by a piece-wise linear function with enough cut-points - but the question is: how practical is that for your purposes? Does having a large number of parameters in your model pose any problems? Sometimes having a single parametric functional form that is easily expressed is worth the *slight* loss of model fit as measured by something like the AIC (when compared with a very complex functional form with only slightly better AIC).